# Quel est l'équivalent du mot anglais "Buddy" en argot ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, argot

En anglais, tu peux dire « Hey!  How is it going **bud**?! »  ou en grec, tu mets **re** comme « How is it going re??! »

Quel est l'équivalent de ce mot anglais en français qui est utilisé fréquemment ?

« Salut! ça va ___ »?

Donc, quelles phrases peut-on utiliser avec ses amis ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il y a de nombreuses variantes existantes bien entendu. Parmi les plus employées :

*(Je n'ai pas inclus le "ça va" dans les exemples, et j'ai conservé un "Salut" neutre. Ca n'était pas le coeur de la question, et il y a en effet des quantités de variantes de "salut" et de "ça va".)*

> Salut **mon pote** / Salut **les** [**p'tits**] **potes**
>   Salut [**mon**] **gars** *(article parfois omis mais fréquent)* / Salut **les** [**p'tits**] **gars** *(et si quelqu'un du sud de la France pouvait confirmer, je crois qu'ils disent **garçon(s)** à la place, sans article)(voire **gazier** qui, je crois, est employé aussi, mais je ne saurais pas le localiser, avis à ceux qui sauraient)*
>   Salut **mec** *(attention : pas d'article ici au singulier)* / Salut **les mecs**
>   Salut **les copains** / Salut **les aminches** *(étrangement, dans les deux cas, pas d'usage au singulier)*
>   Salut **la compagnie** / Salut **tout le monde** *(pour ces deux variantes collectives, cette fois plus logiquement, pas d'équivalent au singulier) (ou à la rigueur... "Salut tout seul" mais uniquement en réponse ironique à "Salut tout le monde")*

voire peut-être un peu plus rarement :

> Salut **l'ami** / Salut **les amis** *(de moins en moins employé, mais probablement encore utilisé, selon le lieu)*
>   Salut **p'tit père** / Salut **les p'tits pères** *(attention l'adjectif n'est **pas** facultatif)*
>   Salut **mon** [**p'tit**] **loup** / **les** [**p'tits**] **loups** *(adjectif fréquent mais pas toujours présent)*
>   Salut **gros** *(je l'ajoute à titre anecdotique en tant que lorrain, où c'est probablement un peu plus employé qu'ailleurs. Adressé indifféremment de la corpulence... et du genre de l'interlocuteur.)*
>   Salut **ma couille** *(pardon d'avance aux défenseurs du bon goût que j'aurai immanquablement choqués, mais on l'entend donc je le cite. Ne s'adresse qu'au singulier, et qu'à un interlocuteur masculin.)*

Dernière note à propos de l'usage de "ça va" en saluant :
Il me semble qu'on dit un peu plus souvent "ça va" (ou une variante) juste *après* avoir salué, quelle que soit la variante qu'on aura préférée. Exemples :

> Salut l'ami ! Ca va ?
>   Salut les p'tits potes ! Ca roule ?

Comment: Merci pour votre aide mon pote! :).  J'étais curieux d'équivalent pour buddy en français, mais, à mon avis, je pensais que "le pote" ne semble pas bon, ni a bien sonné (I think I said this write) comme le Grec "re" (je suis grec, ainsi, j'ai un avis biaisé).  Un autre chose, mon nomme est << s.a.v.v.a.s >> , n'est pas << s.a.w.a.s >> :).  Ne vous inquiétez pas, ce n'est pas un problème :).   Mais, comme j'ai dit avant, merci pour votre aide.

Comment: @Romain : Ah tiens, un lorrain aussi. :) Pour préciser, la variante "salut gros" s'utilise un peu partout, l'ayant entendu partout dans le sud de la France et à Paris. Le "salut" est parfois remplacé par "ouais", ce qui donne "ouais gros", mais c'est (encore) plus familier.

Comment: @PaulPicard Oui, maintenant que tu en parles, c'est vrai que je crois l'avoir entendu dans d'autres contextes, hors Lorraine. La version idiomatique lorraine à laquelle je pensais ça serait plutôt le fameux « Comment qu'c'est, [gros](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQyCkwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Ddtu9ccilZrM&ei=X2UuVdTMGIvW7AbAkoCYDQ&usg=AFQjCNGTrXz93alGDUWpKnG-uO4A2TYeHg&sig2=HtfCOdS1bGnb4dSQyt_f0g&bvm=bv.90790515,d.ZGU) ? ». Merci en tous cas, j'ai rectifié.

Comment: On entend « _salut le gros_ » au Qc selon moi (mon gros ami  !, 1740 - donc l'adj. est substantivé sans ami). Facilement aussi je l'aime-il neige gros; je note ça pcq Rey dit que la différence d'emploi grand/gros est très nuancée dans le sud de la République.

Comment: Et c'est sans parler des variations qui doivent surement exister aussi en québecois... Cela dit, réponse plutôt complète, je pense qu'en la matière il est quasiment impossible d'être exhaustif...

Answer (score 4):

*Mon vieux* ! Pour renforcer une autre interjection (autres réponses), ou de manière autonome, avec des nuances :

> ***Adj.***
>   I, A, 4.[Souvent en incise, dans des phrases interj.; la notion d'âge disparaît; l'adj. sert d'intensif dans des cont. souvent dépréc.]
>   **a**) *Fam. ou pop.* [Sans valeur dépréc., renforce une interj. amicale]
>   *Vieux fou; (ma) vieille branche; vieille cloche; mon vieux pote; mon (bon) vieux* (+ subst. ou nom propre). *Voyons, vieux frère,
>   faites-nous pas une tête pareille* (Courteline, *Train 8 h. 47*, 1888,
>   p. 181).
>
> ***Subst.***
>  II, A, 4.
>   **a**) [En incise ou en interj. amicale; la notion d'âge disparaît et le
>   fém. peut servir à désigner une pers. du sexe
>   masculin] *Cher, chère vieux, vieille, mon (bon) vieux, ma (bonne)
>   vieille. Le pêcheur (...) ayant reconnu le facteur, cria: − Bonjour,
>   ma vieille!* (Estaunié, *Vie secrète*, 1908, p. 321). *Il gesticule
>   sur le quai et gueule d'un trottoir à l'autre, interpellant ses
>   connaissances: − Eh vieux! Tu paies un verre!* (Dabit, *Hôtel*, 1929,
>   p. 51).
>  − [Pour traduire la compassion] *Le maire de Fenouille
>   (...) baisse la tête. On dirait qu'il pleure. − Allons, allons, mon
>   vieux... − Tais-toi* (Bernanos, *M. Ouine*, 1943, p. 1438).
>   **b**) [En incise ou en interj. méprisante ou agacée] *Allons, tais-toi,
>   vieux, tu radotes* (Erckm.-Chatr., *Ami Fritz*, 1864, p. 32).
>  **c**)
>   *Mon vieux!* [Interjection traduisant la surprise ou l'indignation; le renvoi au référent « homme ou femme », âgé ou non, disparaît
>   complètement] *Eh ben, mon vieux!... Nom d'un chien, nous le verrons
>   bien si y a pas plan!* (Courteline, *Train 8 h. 47*, 1888, p. 157).−
>   *C'est Charles Faroux qui m'a emmené en auto. − Mon vieux!... C'est joli, en cette saison?* (Colette, *Sido*, 1929, p. 146).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé*, TLFi - « [*vieux*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vieux) » ]

L'emploi familier du nom c'est 1781; *mon vieux !*, 1828; *vieux !*, 1836; *ma vieille !* entre hommes, 1843. Contra français d'Afrique, *personnage important*. (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sous dir. A. Rey, *ed. Le Robert*, « vieux »).

Comment: Ah bien vu je l'avais oublié celui-là, et c'est vrai que c'est très courant aussi !

Answer (score 2):

En français on parle de **pote** ou **mec**. Entre amis on peut dire :

> Salut ! ça va mon pote ? 
>   Salut ! ça va mec ?

Answer (score 1):

Valable dans le Nord :

> Salut **biloute** !

Comment: Une [référence](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/biloute). Merci.